# Method to ls and awk directory contents into a shell variable

Tags: unix, shell, freebsd, sh

I'm struggling to find some way to express this in some other fashion that will yield the appropriate output:

```
var="$(ls /var/run/ | grep searchterm | awk {'NR == 2'})"
```

I've seen on places like shellcheck to use a glob or loop but my research so far hasn't come up with anything to do it so that I can get the result as a variable rather than just echoing or printing the content.

Are there any methods to do this?

Comment: What is your end goal that you wish to accomplish with capturing this information into a shell variable?    If you edit and expand your question to cover why you want to do this, the answer may become clearer.  Thank you.

Comment: It is part of a custom Icinga plugin I am writing for myself.

There is 4 files in the directory - 3 have static names - 1 doesn't. I need to evaluate the contents of these files for the plugin.

The non-statically named file does have some part of the file name that is static to itself and separate from the rest which is what the grep searchterm is.

The variable itself is used to take some other actions later.

Comment: (1) Why are you doing `NR == 2`?  (2) If you use `awk`, you should put the entire `awk` program in quotes; e.g., `'{NR == 2}'`, with the curly braces inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var="$( find /var/run -iregex "$YOUR_REGEX" 2> /dev/null )"
```

Of course, `man find` to learn some limitations of the `-iregex` option.

If the searchterm is not too complex, you might use `-iname "*$SEARCHTERM*"` instead.

In general, parsing the output of `ls` is something you really should avoid.

Comment: This worked. I had to use a -type flag as well, but it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is

> There are four files in the directory — three have static names
>   (e.g., `red`, `blue` and `green`) and one doesn’t. 
>   But I know that the fourth one will have `foo` in its name. 
>   I want to get that fourth filename. 
>   Obviously, I can safely search for `foo`,
>   because none of the static names contain `foo`.

then all you need to do is

```
var="$(echo /var/run/*foo*)"
```

If you’re just working in the current directory, and you do

```
var="$(echo *foo*)"
```

and the fourth filename might begin with a **`-`** (dash),
the above can fail. 
(Also, either of the above commands can fail
if the filename might contain `\` (backslash).) 
But

```
var="$(printf '%s' *foo*)"
```

or

```
var="$(printf '%s' /var/run/*foo*)"
```

should work.

Of course, if the fourth filename might begin with a **`.`** (dot),
you have another problem.